# BCR402R - what is the purpose of Rext in this LED driver?

Tags: led, resistors, current-source, constant-current

I'd like to know what is(are) the purpose(s) of Rext in the BCR402R LE driver circuit.

The BCR402R is a 20 mA constant current LED driver. The application circuit (see below) shows an external resistor Rext which isn't described in the datasheet. So two questions: 1. What is the purpose or Rext? 2. If I omit Rext, should I leave pin 4 open or connect to +Vs?

[image]

[BCR402R old datasheet](http://www.silicalighting.eu/fileadmin/data_sheets/Infineon/BCR402R_datasheet.pdf) - [Newer datasheet](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/bcr402r.pdf?folderId=db3a30431400ef68011407a9cfc70181&fileId=db3a30431400ef68011407bc2b0a0189)

*(My thoughts: I expect that pin 4 is normally left unconnected, and Rext either allows to get more than 20 mA current from the driver, or it moves the heat out of the LED driver to an external resistor to get better cooling of the LED driver.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [updated datasheet](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/bcr402r.pdf?folderId=db3a30431400ef68011407a9cfc70181&fileId=db3a30431400ef68011407bc2b0a0189) explains this better. Try to always use the manufacturer's website copy of the datasheet for the most up to date information.

> BCR402R serves as an easy to use constant current source for LEDs. In stand alone application an external resistor can be connected to adjust the current from 20 mA to 60 mA. Rext can be determined by using the diagram 'Output current versus external resistor', or by refering to diagram 'Output current versus reference voltage'. Look for your desired output current on the y axis and read out the corresponding Vdrop. Calculate Rext: Rext = Vdrop / (Iout -(Vdrop/Rint))

If not used, Rext is omitted/left open.

Additionally, the [Application Note](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/AN066.pdf?folderId=db3a304313b8b5a60113d4239297042f&fileId=db3a3043163797a601167b578d73115f) provides further information and typical circuits.

Answer (score 3):

It allows you to increase the current. 
To do so, you need to know the value of the internal R : it's about 0.6(V)/0.01(I) = 60 ohms. Rext=60 ohms would double the current to 20ma.

Leave the pin open; connecting it to Vs is the same as asking for infinite current; not a good idea...

Comment: No need to know the internal resistor when you know the voltage across it (0.6V). The current through the external resistor adds to the current without external resistor.